WebSocket Disconnects and "Unknown" Error on Firefox and Safari, but Works on Chrome
Sometimes, while chatting, I experience issues with the chat list. Occasionally, the WebSocket disconnects and shows "Unknown" on Firefox and Safari, but Google Chrome seems to work properly. When I refresh the page, the same "Unknown" error persists. Additionally, the browser occasionally hangs, requiring me to close and reopen it.
     <div>
          <p id="status">WebSocket Common : <span id="ws-status">Unknown</span></p>
          <p id="status">WebSocket Group: <span id="ws-status-group">Unknown</span></p>
          <p id="status">WebSocket Chat: <span id="ws-status-chat">Unknown</span></p>
        </div>
    
    var socket = io({
            reconnection: true,         // Enable automatic reconnection
            reconnectionAttempts: Infinity, // Number of reconnection attempts (Infinity = unlimited)
            reconnectionDelay: 1000,    // Time in ms to wait before trying to reconnect
            reconnectionDelayMax: 5000  // Maximum delay between reconnections
          });
    
       const statusElement = document.getElementById('ws-status');
    
          socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected');
            statusElement.textContent = 'Connected';
          });
    
    
          socket.on("disconnect", (reason, details) => {
            // the reason of the disconnection, for example "transport error"
            console.log('Disconnect ==>> ', reason);
    
            // the low-level reason of the disconnection, for example "xhr post error"
            console.log('Disconnect ==>> ', details.message);
    
            // some additional description, for example the status code of the HTTP response
            console.log('Disconnect ==>> ', details.description);
    
            // some additional context, for example the XMLHttpRequest object
            console.log('Disconnect ==>> ', details.context);
            statusElement.textContent = 'Disconnected';
    
          });
    
          socket.on('reconnect', (data) => {
            console.log('reconnect ==>> ', data);
            statusElement.textContent = 'Reconnected';
            socket.connect();
          });
    
          socket.on('reconnect_attempt', (data) => {
            console.log('reconnect_attempt ==>> ', data);
            statusElement.textContent = 'Reconnecting...';
            socket.connect();
          });
    
          socket.on('reconnect_error', (data) => {
            console.log('reconnect_error ==>> ', data);
            statusElement.textContent = 'Reconnect Error';
            socket.connect();
          });
    
        });


Show me error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/2LvZI6M6.png

